# How to pre-select an option in mat-autocomplete

Tags: angular-material

I have a create page where user can select an item from the `<mat-autocomplete>`. I have an edit page where I want the option selected by the user to be pre-selected.

Answer (score 0):

Need to assign a FormControl object on the html input element as shown below. Then in the TS file you can call setValue on the FormControl object to set an initial value.

```
*.HTML file ->
<input matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">

*.TS file ->
 myControl = new FormControl();
 ngOnInit(): void {
     this.myControl.setValue('value to pre-select');
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to this anser

Answer (score -1):

Without some for your code its a bit difficult to help you, but using the example on the material.angular.io site.

```
filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;

ngOnInit() {
      this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
         .startWith(null)
         .map(val => val ? this.filter(val) : this.options.slice()); }

filter(val: string): string[] {
  return this.options.filter(option =>
    option.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0); }
```

You can pass the users pre-selected value to the **.startWith()** operator.